# Writing each element of list in a tuple as a separate column of a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a data structure that I want to write to a csv fie in **1 row only**.
This was when the next iteration is run, it adds a new row for each of the header fields of the csv I am creating.

For instance, the row I am trying to write to csv looks like this. Here, I want each element of list to go in a separate column. Meaning, 4.1% should go to column 2, 11.5% to column 3, and so on.

```
rowdict = {tuple:4}

('Row 1 data', ['4.1%', '11.5%', '21.1%', '2.6%', '14.8%', '0.4%', '9.6%', '35.6%', '0.0%', '0.4%'], [11, 31, 57, 7, 40, 1, 26, 96, 0, 1], 270)
```

My snippet:

```
f = open(completeName + '.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
    with f:
        # identifying header
        header = header_list
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
        # writing data row-wise into the csv file
        writer.writeheader()
        all_perce_val = ["{:.1%}".format(x) for x in all_fractions_list]
        for i in range(1,len(all_perce_val)):
            writer.writerow((str(os.path.split(os.path.split(directory)[0])[1]), all_perce_val, count_of_each_type, total_cycle_count))
    print("Finished writing the csv file at:"+completeName)
```

I am struggling to figure out how to pass the multiple lists that I have to writerow() so that it writes them the way I need.

Update: I changed my approach and tried using dataframes

```
data_row = []
    data_row.extend([str(os.path.split(os.path.split(directory)[0])[1])])
    data_row.extend(all_perce_val)
    data_row.extend(count_of_each_type)
    data_row.extend([total_cycle_count])
    final_data_row = [data_row]
    df_row = pd.DataFrame(data=final_data_row, columns=header).fillna('')
    mode = 'w' if header_flag else 'a'
    df_row.to_csv(completeName + '.csv', mode=mode, index=None)
    header_flag = False
```

However, I want to avoid writing the column names with each loop iteration. The above snippet is struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just unpack the lists before using it in `writer.writerow`.

```
>>> row=('Row 1 data', ['4.1%', '11.5%', '21.1%', '2.6%', '14.8%', '0.4%', '9.6%', '35.6%', '0.0%', '0.4%'], [11, 31, 57, 7, 40, 1, 26, 96, 0, 1], 270)
>>> row=(row[0],*row[1],*row[2],row[3])
>>> row
('Row 1 data', '4.1%', '11.5%', '21.1%', '2.6%', '14.8%', '0.4%', '9.6%', '35.6%', '0.0%', '0.4%', 11, 31, 57, 7, 40, 1, 26, 96, 0, 1, 270)
```

Now you are good to use `writer.writerow(row)`

Comment: Thanks. I switched to using dataframes to_csv approach.
Could you assist with the question above in my update?

Comment: Ok, I maintained a flag for the header field and that did it. Thanks!